# Jfrog Artifactory: How to delete old snapshot artifacts

Tags: maven

I had a task to delete old SNAPSHOT artefacts which are under many folders/directories.

We can't go and delete each and every artefact manually so I would like to go with restAPI.

For clear info:

1. https://artifactory.com/artifactory/maven-local/com/aa/bbb/cccc/dddd/XYZ-SNAPSHOT/abc.jar
2. https://artifactory.com/artifactory/maven-local/com/aa/bbb/cccc/dddd/XYZ-SNAPSHOT/xyz.jar
3. https://artifactory.com/artifactory/maven-local/com/aa/bbb/cccc/eeee/XYZ-SNAPSHOT/pqr.jar
4. https://artifactory.com/artifactory/maven-local/com/aa/bbb/dddd/eeee/XYZ-SNAPSHOT/lmn.jar

Above 4 examples have different directories.

My script needs to go each and every directory and have to verify for XYZ-SNAPSHOT, if it found then we can make a url and delete through CURL.

How can we achieve this? Or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably want to use [Artifactory Query Language (AQL)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) which is the easiest way to find artifacts and modules according to patterns. You can find bunch of examples in the page. Moreover, to perform the deletion easily and even automate the process in the future, I advise using JFrog CLI. You can also read this interesting [blog](https://jfrog.com/blog/aql-cli-a-match-made-in-heaven/) about similar use case.

Also, there is the ['Max Unique Snapshots'](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-Maven,Gradle,IvyandSBTRepositories) field in your local Maven repository settings. You can use that for Artifactory to keep a specified number of unique snapshots per artifact.